# how to store string which have diacritics in java

Tags: java, database, string, character-encoding

I have a `<input/>` tag on jsp whare user can put company names and then i store that name into database and show that name again on view page(result jsp).

Every thing works fine if I only deal with `Romanized names without diacritics`.

but if someone has entered company name as `"Československá obchodní banka"` then string gets changed and on view page i get some garbage value.

So my quest is how can i store `Romanized names with diacritics` in java variable and in database so that i can show the same string what user has entered in `<input/>` field on view page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into character encoding. Put UTF-8 through out the application.
HTML/JSP -> Servlets/Controller -> Database and you should be fine.

Comment: I am using UTF-8 character set but problem is still there

Comment: You must have missed somewhere in the chain. Try to debug and see where the conversion is getting wrong.